# Cut off text character 'IIf' + 'Left' (?)

Tags: ms-access

Been struggling with a formula in a calculated field to cut off the last character IF it is a text, otherwise the return should be itself. 
(I think the 'iif' and the 'left' formulas could be used)

Should be simple, but some help would be appreciated!

Comment: great! thanks for the quick response. I was not aware that the calculated fields has that much less function options than queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but should get you headed in the right direction. Try: `=IIf(IsNumeric(Right([YourField],1), [YourField],Left ([YourField], Len([YourField])-1))`

Translation:

```
If the last character Is a digit Then
     return the field 
Else 
     Return the field minus the last character 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be:

```
ValidatedNumber = Left([CheckNumber], Len([CheckNumber]) - 1 + Abs(IsNumeric(Right([CheckNumber], 1))))
```